# Create zip file from all files in folder

Tags: c#, zip

I'm trying to create a zip file from all files in a folder, but can't find any related snippet online. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("somedir path");
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
zip.AddFiles(dir.getfiles());
zip.SaveTo("some other path");
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

edit: I only want to zip the files from a folder, not it's subfolders.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Referencing System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in your Project

```
using System.IO.Compression;

string startPath = @"c:\example\start";//folder to add
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";//URL for your ZIP file
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";//path to extract
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

To use files only, use:

```
//Creates a new, blank zip file to work with - the file will be
//finalized when the using statement completes
using (ZipArchive newFile = ZipFile.Open(zipName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(myPath))
    {
        newFile.CreateEntryFromFile(file, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
    }              
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. This sample zippes all files and folders in a folder. I only want to zip the files from a folder.

Comment: Yeah, sure - downvote me when I answered this and hour BEFORE OP specified they didn't want the subfolders included. ahem... how is this a bad answer given it was made before the edit?

Comment: I'm very gratefull that you took the time and effort to try to help me. Both the sample and the title clearly stated that I only wanted to zip files. I just thought that I should state it more clearly, that is why I added the edit.

Comment: Oh lol I didn't realize you were the one who downvoted me lol. No worries.

Comment: Oh, should i not have? I just thought that since it's not exactly what I'm looking for I should -1 it?

Comment: Any idea how I can save the ZipArchive as a zip file to disk?

Comment: Here's the MSDN on it. Zipmode.Create should create a new file. I've heard there are some issues if you try to create the zip in the same folder you are compressing - but essentially, ZipArchiveMode.Create should place the file in the directory you choose. Anyway, check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions(v=vs.110).aspx and please remember to select an answer when you're done. Thanks!

Comment: If it gives you any problems, try saving to C:myzip.zip (no backslash) and then look in your project folder for the file. If you still have problems, let me know what's going on and we'll fix it.

Comment: I had to add references (dlls) `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` to use the class `ZipFile`.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` in your Project, your code can be something like:

```
string startPath = @"some path";
string zipPath = @"some other path";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(startPath);

using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, file);
        }
    }
}
```

In some folders though you may have problems with permissions.

To make your zipfile portable on UNIX system, you should pay attention to:

- [Compression.ZipFile support for Unix Permissions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1548)

For instance, one may use mod "644":

```
var entry = newFile.CreateEntryFromFile(file, file);
entry.ExternalAttributes |= (Convert.ToInt32("644", 8) << 16);
```

Comment: Pay attention to [file permission](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1548)

Answer (score -1):

This does not need loops. For VS2019 + .NET FW 4.7+ did this...

1. Find ZipFile in Manage Nuget Packages browse, or use

https://www.nuget.org/packages/40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem/

2. Then use:

   using System.IO.Compression;

As an example, below code fragment will pack and unpack a directory (use false to avoid packing subdirs)

```
    string zippedPath = "c:\\mydir";                   // folder to add
    string zipFileName = "c:\\temp\\therecipes.zip";   // zipfile to create
    string unzipPath = "c:\\unpackedmydir";            // URL for ZIP file unpack
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zippedPath, zipFileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFileName, unzipPath);
```