# use loop to check the files in directory and add the files that have the same date on the filename to a zip folder

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check the files in the directory which all the files have the format like filename_20200219 and zip all the files which have the same date based on the date from the filename. How can this be done?

For example, a_20200219, b_20200219, c_20200220, d_20200220

The output after zipping should be:

a_20200219 and b_20200219 in a zip folder

c_20200220 and d_20200220 in another zip folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Can you show some code please.

Comment: actually i have no idea to solve this problem

Comment: Use Google: 'c# get file from path' will get you [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) which returns a list of files. Use `linq` to get the matching files and then Google again: 'c# add file to zip'  will give you ideas for the last part.

Comment: For the first part use the link of @PeterSmith. For the second part you can use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732407/create-zip-file-from-all-files-in-folder

Comment: actually im using 7zip to zip the folder

Answer (score 0):

Use [Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_) to retrieve all the files in a directory.
Than [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Path_GetFileNameWithoutExtension_System_String_) to get its name.
Than split it on the '_' with `var elements = fileName.Split('_');`.
At position 1 there will be the date `var date = elements[1];`.
So now you can group files having the same date.

To be able to [create a zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_CreateFromDirectory_System_String_System_String_) file you need to create a [new directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_CreateDirectory_System_String_) and [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_) there your files having the same date.

I hope I was helpful