# How to download pdf files from file path stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have spent about 3 days on trying to figure out how to download my files I am retrieving from the database using a LINQ Method. I am able to get the file paths that are stored in my database but have no idea how to download them from my controller.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult ExportFile(string[] years, string[] months, string[]radio, string[] acctNum)
{
        Statement theStatementPath = new Statement();
        var thePath = theStatementPath.statementPath;

        List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();

        if (years != null)
        {
            using (var db = new dbentities())
            {
                foreach (var aYear in years)
                {

                    List<string> paths = db.Statement
                                           .Where(x => x.statementYear == aYear)
                                           .Select(y => y.statementPath).ToList();
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (var year in paths)
                    {
                        builder.Append(paths).ToString();
                    }

                    string result = builder.ToString();
                    string contentType = "application/zip";
                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(result);
                    string file = result;

                    return File(fileBytes, contentType, file);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this and everything I read online doesn't seem like what I need and never works for what I am trying to do. Please any help or guidance would be so awesome!

Here's my model if you need it:

```
public partial class Statement
{
    public System.DateTime statementDate { get; set; }
    public string statementYear { get; set; }
    public string statementMonth { get; set; }
    public string statementPath { get; set; }
}
```

> Heres is my HTML:Index.cs

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="ExportFile">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="my-container">
            <label class="acct-text" for="AccountNumber"> Step 1 - Enter Account Number :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="accNum" id="accountNum" placeholder="Account Number">
            <p id="Status"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="year" for="Year">Step 2 - Select Statement Year(s) :</label>

        <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_1"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[0]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_2"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[1]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_3"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[2]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_4"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[3]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_5"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[4]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_6"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[5]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_7"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[6]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_8"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[7]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_9"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[8]</label>
        </div>

        <button id="selection" class="select-all-years">Select All Years</button>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><label class="month-text">Step 3 - Select Statement(s) Month :</label></p>
        <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container">

            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_jan" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[0]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_feb" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[1]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_mar" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[2]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_apr" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[3]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_may" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[4]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_jun" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[5]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_jul" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[6]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_aug" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[7]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_sept" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[8]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_oct" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[9]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_nov" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[10]</label>
            <label><input class="month" id="chkbx_dec" name="month" type="checkbox"> @ViewBag.months[11]</label>

        </div>
        <button id="selection" class="select-all">Select All Months</button>
    </div>

    <p><label for="Delivery">Step 4 - Select Delivery Method :</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="radio" name="radiodecision" id="download" /> Download Statements</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="radio" name="radiodecision" id="email" /> Email Statements</label></p>
    <input type="text" class='txbx' hidden="hidden" />
    <p class="message" hidden="hidden">* To send to multiple recipients, separate the email addresses using a comma "," </p>
    <p class="message" hidden="hidden">* Statement(s) will be delivered via FMBSECURE</p>

    <input type="button" name="submit_form" runat="server" value="RetrieveStatements" id="main-content-submit">

</form>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you execute this code? Do you get some result, exception or smth?

Comment: if the file is saved on disk, then just use the path and convert it to public `url` to be able to use `HTTP Requests` on that `url`

Comment: @Borka So right now it is its giving me an error saying result is not good because result is coming back as [System.Collection.String] instead of as my file paths.

Comment: @iSR5 So the file is save on the server. I then have all of the file paths for the files saved in my database as statementPath.

Comment: `builder.ToString();` has a list of paths, you'll need to loop over each path to process it.

Comment: `foreach(var path in paths) byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);`

Comment: @iSR5 `builder.ToString();` is string. I dont think he can iterate it. But on the other hand, if every path is a pdf and you need a zip, then you need to read every path as @iSR5 said and put it in a zip file

Comment: @Borka so, one thing is sometimes ill get back thousands of of files and it take like 10 minutes to loop over those paths. Also, could you give an example of how to put them into a zip file?

Comment: @iSR5 if i foreach the paths and then set byte[] fileBytes to System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path); so i put the rest of the lines of code including the return File() inside that foreach block of code?

Comment: I just noticed this `builder.Append(paths).ToString();` so the builder.ToString() would only return the name of the collection. ;(

Comment: @iSR5 yeah thats what I am trying to change.. it throws an error saying result is the name of that collection.

Comment: Well if you have many files then you'll need to create some kind of background service to create the zip, store it in the server and notify the user when their file is ready for download. Or you can limit the amount of files somehow, idk your requirements. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732567/3120130) answer for creating zip file

Comment: Another thing is that the first for loop will execute only once since the loop will break once it reaches the return statement. You might need to rework that as well

Comment: @Borka How would I go about changing where the return statement goes?

Comment: For every year you have a statements that are PDFs that the user needs to download?

Comment: Yeah so the whole app will give them the option to choose a month or month(s) and a year or year(s). Then when they click the button on my form it will run my commands and download those specific pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution to your problem

Note: I haven't tested this code so it might need some little tweaks.

I've also put some comments in the code to explain it further

```
public ActionResult ExportFile(string[] years, string[] months, string[] radio, string[] acctNum)
{
    Statement theStatementPath = new Statement();
    var thePath = theStatementPath.statementPath;

    List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();

    if (years != null)
    {
        using (var db = new dbentities())
        {
            // we will store the contents of the zip file in memory, 
            // just be careful if you have too many files you might run out of memory
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // create a zip archive and pass the memory as a parameter
                // you dont need a path, cause as like I said the zip will be in memory
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (var aYear in years)
                    {
                        List<string> paths = db.Statement
                            .Where(x => x.statementYear == aYear)
                            .Select(y => y.statementPath)
                            .ToList();

                        // iterate all the paths for a given year
                        foreach (var path in paths)
                        {
                            // check if the file at the path exists
                            if (File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                // load the file into the zip archive
                                zip.CreateEntryFromFile(path, path);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // once you iterate all years, return the zip file to browser
                    return File(zip, "application/zip", "pdfs.zip");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the help but I couldn't get this to work